# R: repeated values in a column, how to replace with single value

Tags: r

I have a table with dates in column 1 (Column titled "Date") and values in columns 1 and 2 (Columns titled "A" and "B").
df

```
    Date A B
1 1/1/16 X X
2 1/2/16 X Y
3 1/3/16 X Y
4 1/4/16 Y Y
5 1/5/16 Y X
```

etc.

I need to create additional 4 and 5th columns A* and B* that contains the following:

For each row:

For column A* - If value in column A in the current row is different from the value in column A in previous row then insert new value, if the value is the same then insert nothing.

For column B* - If value in column B in the current row is different from the value in column B in previous row then insert new value, if the value is the same then insert nothing.

Desired output:

```
    Date A B A* B*
1 1/1/16 X X  X  X
2 1/2/16 X Y  -  Y
3 1/3/16 X Y  -  -
4 1/4/16 Y Y  Y  -
5 1/5/16 Y X  -  X
```

What is the best way to do this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

In base R, we can first use `diff`to identify changes in the columns then use `ifelse` to impute* the changeover value or a `"-"` and save the result as new columns:

```
df[,c("A*", "B*")] <- lapply(df[-1], function(x) {
                        ifelse(c(1,diff(as.numeric(as.factor(x)))), as.character(x), "-")})
df
  #     Date A B A* B*
  # 1 1/1/16 X X  X  X
  # 2 1/2/16 X Y  -  Y
  # 3 1/3/16 X Y  -  -
  # 4 1/4/16 Y Y  Y  -
  # 5 1/5/16 Y X  -  X
```

*Although it's odd that numeric values work as the condition of the if else function, note that R converts all zeroes to FALSE and all other numbers to TRUE*

Answer (score 1):

```
library(data.table);
df$A1 = ifelse(duplicated(rleid(df$A)), "-", df$A)
df$B1 = ifelse(duplicated(rleid(df$B)), "-", df$B)
df
    Date A B A1 B1
1 1/1/16 X X  X  X
2 1/2/16 X Y  -  Y
3 1/3/16 X Y  -  -
4 1/4/16 Y Y  Y  -
5 1/5/16 Y X  -  X
```

Note: `rleid` stands for `run length encoding (id?)` perhaps. Basically what it does is create an id for each piece of duplicated sequence. Thus each duplicated sequence will be labeled differently. Then with the `duplicated` function which labels duplicated values as `TRUE` except for the first. You can pick duplicated values except for the first one for every duplicated block.

Comment: whats "rleid" function?

Comment: could not find function "rleid"

Comment: Did you load the package `data.table`? It 's from `data.table` package.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R method using the `rle` function:

```
# fill new variable with desired value
df$A1 <- "-"
# fill it in with original value
df$A1[c(1, head(cumsum(rle(df$A)$length), -1)+1)] <- rle(df$A)$value
# repeat for B
df$B1 <- "-"
df$B1[c(1, head(cumsum(rle(df$B)$length), -1)+1)] <- rle(df$B)$value
```

This results in

```
df
    Date A B A1 B1
1 1/1/16 X X  X  X
2 1/2/16 X Y  -  Y
3 1/3/16 X Y  -  -
4 1/4/16 Y Y  Y  -
5 1/5/16 Y X  -  X
```

Note that the variables A and B must be character, which is why I use the as.is=TRUE argument below.

**data**

```
df <- read.table(header= TRUE, text="    Date A B
1 1/1/16 X X
2 1/2/16 X Y
3 1/3/16 X Y
4 1/4/16 Y Y
5 1/5/16 Y X", as.is=TRUE)
```